# Haskell: "Couldn't match expected type IO () with IO ThreadId"

Tags: haskell, concurrency, io

I'm new to concurrency in Haskell and I'm trying to get a result where a new MVar is made in the `main` thread, is passed over empty to the `userThread` thread, which takes a character input from the user, then puts that value in an MVar and has the `main` thread print it.

Here is what I have so far

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Random
import Text.Printf

data Msg = C Char | Time


main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  hSetEcho stdin False

  -- shared resources
  chan <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ userThread chan
  --r <- takeMVar chan
  --show(r)


userThread :: MVar Msg -> IO ()
userThread chan = forever $ do
  x <- getChar
  putMVar chan (C x)
```

Right now, I'm stuck on trying to put the entered char into the MVar, I've pasted the error below

```
assignment1.hs:20:3: error:
    * Couldn't match type `ThreadId' with `()'
      Expected type: IO ()
        Actual type: IO ThreadId
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: forkIO $ userThread chan
      In the expression:
        do { hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering;
             hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering;
             hSetEcho stdin False;
             chan <- newEmptyMVar;
             .... }
      In an equation for `main':
          main
            = do { hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering;
                   hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering;
                   hSetEcho stdin False;
                   .... }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be a great help!
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

`forkIO $ userThread chan` is an IO action which returns `ThreadId`, and being the last statement in the `main` `do` block, it makes `main` return that as well. However, you declared `main :: IO ()` so there's a type mismatch.

Simply return a dummy tuple.

```
main = do
   ...
   forkIO $ userThread chan
   return ()
```

(There's also a [`void`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:void) library function for this, but you can ignore it.)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I can now get the program to compile and print my char using `deriving (Show)`, however, the output for this is for example `C 'g'`, how could I get it to just print the character pressed by the user?

Comment: @SebMarsh you can define your own `Show` instance or you could define a function `Msg -> String` or `Msg -> Text` that pretty prints a message however you like (then call `putStrLn` to write it to stdout)

Comment: Thanks again. As I replied to jberryman I figured that I could use something like this to get my Msg data to act like a String if it's a Char. How would I start out in doing this? I haven't used my own instances before so I'm somewhat lost.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're going to get this error over and over as you learn haskell, I wanted to unpack it for you:

```
assignment1.hs:20:3: error:
```

GHC is giving you the file, line number and column number: `file:line:col`

```
    * Couldn't match type `ThreadId' with `()'
      Expected type: IO ()
        Actual type: IO ThreadId
```

`Expected type` refers to the type GHC is expecting for an expression, based on the context e.g. a type signature you provided, or the way you use a value returned from that expression. `Actual type` is the... actual type of the expression, e.g. a literal `'c'` has type `Char`, `map fst [('c', undefined)]` has actual type `[Char]`, etc.

```
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: forkIO $ userThread chan
```

This ^ is the problem statement. `forkIO` returns a `ThreadId` (which you can see from its type signature). The tricky part here then, I suppose, is to know why the typechecker was expecting a type `IO ()` (because of your type signature, and the fact that the value returned in the last statement of your `do` block will be the type returned, as chi mentions).

It's useful to have `ghci` open to help you answer questions like these as you're developing:

```
Prelude> import Control.Concurrent
Prelude Control.Concurrent> :t forkIO
forkIO :: IO () -> IO ThreadId
Prelude Control.Concurrent> :t ()
() :: ()
Prelude Control.Concurrent> :t repeat ()
repeat () :: [()]
```

The rest is more context which you probably don't need if you have the file in front of you:

```
      In the expression:
        do { hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering;
             hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering;
             hSetEcho stdin False;
             chan <- newEmptyMVar;
             .... }
      In an equation for `main':
          main
            = do { hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering;
                   hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering;
                   hSetEcho stdin False;
                   .... }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand my problem a little bit but now I'm facing an entirely new problem on how to make my Msg type behave like a String. I'd like to put it in an existing list if the typed char is in not in the list BUT if the char already exists in this list, it isn't added and all instances of that char are removed from the list. I'll create another question shortly after a little more research.